Rigify Help: Cannot Connect chain bone
I'm trying to rig a game character with rigify and it keeps giving me a "cannot connect chain bone" error for spine.003? The character in question I've combined parts of the animal rig "cat" with Basic metarig human. But the bones that are being flagged are from the human part of the rig with only the large head/face bones and tail being from the cat itself.
Full Error: 
I've tried having the bones connected and "kept offset" but are virtually occupying the same space both scale 0 to line up but the error keeps appearing. Would anyone be willing to please take a look at the rig and figure out what is going wrong? I've usually manually made rigs with limited features and want to speed up the process wherever I can but I just don't know rigify in order to troubleshoot myself.
Drive link: Character model


There are many issues on cascade:
The whole face has to be rebuilt, because lots of bones need to have their respective head and tail in the same spot, as you find them in the original Face Sample, so I deleted the whole face system from the Metarig in order to generate the body rig.
The first problem that pops up is the fact that the first tail bone (oddly named ORG-spine.003) has to have its Rigify Type property "Connect chain" unticked.

Now the rig gets generated, but it doesn't create a proper neck-head control: to solve you have to select the metarig, go to edit mode and make sure that spine.004 is child of spine.003 (keep offset), while spine.005 and ORG-spine.011 (another odd name) are connected children of the previous bones.
Then go to pose mode and assign to spine.004 a "spines.super_head" Rigify Type.

Now the body rig can be correctly generated:

Back to the Metarig, in edit mode you can add a faces.super_face Sample, upgrade it to the new Face type, and place its bones, paying attention to move the joints without disconnecting them (in the picture below I marked only some of the groups of joints that need to be moved as a whole, not one by one: as a general rule, always use box select or circle select on a joint, then move it in place).

Lastly, make the Face bone child of the ORG-spine.011 (keep offset), and regenerate the rig.

So can I continuously regernate the rig over and over with each iteration? Like add tail generate rig, face generate rig, place face bones generate rig.

yes, absolutely.

Cool it'll be trial and error cause ive  never used rigify before so repsonses might be delayed while I try and work through this.

One thing I will ask. How do I adjust the weights of the rig once I bind the finished result to the mesh? Is it the same as how you would normally

Yes, everything is the same as a standard rig, you will find all deforming bones in the Bone layer named "DEF". All others bones are set to "Non deforming", because they are used for ConTRoL, MeCHanism, or copies of the ORiGinal metarig.

cool beans, i've gotten the tail working but now the face which i've redone is giving me
hassles again. "RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'brow.B.L.004': Input to rig type must be a chain of 2 or more bones.
Incorrect armature for type 'stretchy_chain"? I used the cat face again, should i just use the human face?.

It is generating a rig now but it keeps asking me to "upgrade face rig" when I apply the faces.super_face rig type to the face bone and that is when it says the error message above

Last edit maybe... ~sorry~
Pretty sure it's all working now? If I update the GDrive could I ask you to check over things one last time?
